# ORA-03291: Invalid truncate option - missing STORAGE keyword

Tags: sql, oracle

i have to execute two statements in a sequence. My Statement is as below. I get the above error when i run this.

```
TRUNCATE TABLE MANUAL_LIST_BACKUP
    INSERT INTO MANUAL_LIST_BACKUP AS SELECT * FROM MANUAL_TRANSACTIONS
```

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a syntax error.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Separate the two statements with a `;`