# ssis : execute sql task truncate table statement not working for oracle connection

Tags: oracle, ssis

I am using Oracle provider for ole DB connection to connect to oracle database From SSIS. Test connection is succeeding. Data is also migrating from the csv file to oracle database. But while I am executing truncate table statement of oracle [truncate table Table1 ;] SQL task is failing. Is it related to oracle driver I installed "ODTwithODAC122011" to use Oracle provider for ole DB?
I am getting following error.

> [Execute SQL Task] Error: Executing the query "truncate table Table1
> ;" failed with the following error: "ORA-03291: Invalid truncate
> option - missing STORAGE keyword". Possible failure reasons: Problems
> with the query, "ResultSet" property not set correctly, parameters not
> set correctly, or connection not established correctly.

[ORA-03291](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RTxqJ.jpg)

Comment: There's a possible answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20886341/ora-03291-invalid-truncate-option-missing-storage-keyword please post the actual sql that you are submitting

Comment: _**truncate table table1;**_
@Nick.McDermaid  I used above oracle query to execute 
I am executing this query from execute SQL task using oracle provider for OLE DB connection.

Answer (score 0):

Just use the schema name to reference the table:

```
TRUNCATE TABLE <SCHEMANAME>.<TABLENAME>
```

The same question has been answered in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69759382/)

Comment: if the same question is answered in another post, why did you vote to close this as a duplicate instead of answering?

Comment: @[starball](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11107541/starball): I didn't vote to close it and I answered the question, just put your glasses on!

Comment: my bad. I meant to say "why **didn't** you vote to close"