# SSIS execute SQL task error "ORA-03291: Invalid truncate option - missing STORAGE keyword"

Tags: sql, oracle, ssis

I am running an execute task in my SSIS thru visual studio and am receiving an error "ORA-03291: Invalid truncate option - missing STORAGE keyword". I am connecting with an 'oracle provider for the OLE DB' the code i am using is:

```
truncate table myTable DROP STORAGE;
```

this works fine in the oracle SQL developer but not in the SSIS I have tried using my table space name and delayed validation

Comment: Try removing the "DROP STORAGE" from the statement - it's the default.

Comment: Originally the statement was truncate table myTable; added the Drop Storage because of the error.

Comment: Can't help you I'm not able to run commands in your configuration. Maybe others can

Comment: I'm seeing the exact same issue. I tried both with and without the `DROP STORAGE` clause, and I also tried `BEGIN EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'TRUNCATE TABLE "schema"."table" DROP STORAGE'; END;`. I ran the package from Visual Studio and from the SSIS server (using SSMS). Validation passes, but I get that runtime error. No luck.

Comment: Please, check if my answer below was correct and mark it as the answer.

Answer (score 5):

I was experiencing the same problem, and I found the culprit is the semi-colon (`;`) at the end of the truncate statement. SSIS does not seem to like ending SQL statements with a semi-colon when talking to Oracle. Removing the semi-colon (`;`) at the end of the truncate statement makes the error go away.

The following statements work without raising the ORA - 03291 error:

```sql
TRUNCATE TABLE "schema"."table"

TRUNCATE TABLE "schema"."table" DROP STORAGE
```

However, adding the semi-colon at the end will raise the error again.

Comment: You saved my day!!! `BEGIN EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'TRUNCATE TABLE a;'; END;` produces **ORA-03291**, but `BEGIN EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'TRUNCATE TABLE a'; END;` succeeds (mind the absence of ; in the working command)

Comment: In my case, I have to change the `TRUNCATE <table_name>` for `DELETE FROM <schema>.<table_name>` - I believe this `ORA - 03291` error code is due to admin privileges.